# C++ declarar datos de un arreglo como parametro

Tags: c++, funciones

Digamos que tengo esto:

```
string opciones[] =
    {
        "Registrar estudiante",
        "Consultar estudiante",
        "Eliminar estudiante",
        "Atras"
    };
```

y tengo una funcion asi:

```
construir(string titulo, string opciones[],int n)
```

y luego la dejo asi:

```
construir("Elija una opcion:", string opciones[],4)
```

Puedo llenar directamente el titulo, y la variable n, pero el parametro de arreglo lo pongo asi:

```
construir("Elija una opcion:",{"Registrar","Consultar","Eliminar","Atras"},4)
```

Y me tira esto el compilador:

```
warning: extended initializer lists only available with std c++11 or std gnu++11

error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}' for argument '2' to 'int construir(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string*, int)'|
```

Quisiera saber si se pueden declarar directamente los datos en los parametros de la funcion como lo hice con las otras dos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a analizar el error que has obtenido:

> ```
> warning: extended initializer lists only available with std c++11 or std gnu++11
> ```

La primera frase del error te indica (la traducción es mía) que las listas de inicialización extendidas sólo están disponibles a partir del estándar C++11.

Si te ha dado este error, es posible que tu compilador tenga capacidad para el estándar C++11 pero no esté activada la opción. Intenta pasar `std=c++11` como opción de compilación y te dejará usar las...

#### Listas de inicialización extendidas.

Son una *nueva* característica de C++ introducida en el estándar C++11, permite que (casi) cualquier cosa encerrada entre llaves (`{` y `}`) sea considerada una lista. En concreto una serie de datos del mismo tipo, separados por coma, encerrados entre llaves será traducido como la plantilla [`std::initializer_list`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Esta plantilla contiene un número arbitrario de valores del mismo tipo, pero **no es un arreglo**. Si quisieras usarla en tu función `construir`, deberías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
construir(string titulo, initializer_list<string> opciones);
```

De esta manera, con C++11 o superior, la siguiente llamada sería correcta:

```
construir("Elija una opcion:",{"Registrar","Consultar","Eliminar","Atras"});
```

No sería necesario pasar el tamaño de la lista (tú pasabas un 4) porque el compilador cuenta los elementos y los puedes consultar mediante la función miembro [`std::initializer_list::size`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/size).

#### Listas de inicialización extendidas para construir colecciones.

Como ya ha comentado [Dementor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/51190/2742)<sup>1</sup>, es posible pasar a tu función `construir` un contenedor y éste aceptará una lista de inicialización. Esto se debe a que éste tipo de objetos (los contenedores) tienen un constructor que acepta listas de inicialización.

#### Si no dispones de un compilador C++11 o superior...

... olvídate de pasar una lista de inicialización. Pero tienes la opción de usar plantillas:

```
template <std::size_t TAMANYO>
void construir(std::string, std::string (&opciones)[TAMANYO])
{
    for (std::size_t indice = 0; indice < TAMANYO; ++indice)
        std::cout << "Construyendo " << opciones[indice] << '\n';
}
```

La función se usaría [[así]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mWNfLsEMJvfyPbyh):

```
std::string opciones[] =
{
    "Registrar estudiante",
    "Consultar estudiante",
    "Eliminar estudiante",
    "Atras"
};

template <std::size_t TAMANYO>
void construir(std::string, std::string (&opciones)[TAMANYO])
{
    for (std::size_t indice = 0; indice < TAMANYO; ++indice)
        std::cout << "Construyendo " << opciones[indice] << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    construir("test", opciones);

    return 0;
}
```

No es necesario pasar el parámetro de tamaño porque la plantilla lo detecta.

---

<sup>1</sup>Vaya mal royo de nombre... :'(

Comment: gracias @PaperBirdMaster, aunque intento que funcione con el C++ estandar (no se cual sea, pero creo que es el 98 o algo asi)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar vectores si lo pasas como referencia:

```
void construir(string titulo, const vector<string> &opciones)
{
    int n = opciones.size();
    // ...
}
```

Y luego puedes usar:

```
construir("Elija una opcion:", {"Registrar", "Consultar", "Eliminar", "Atras"});
```

Hay también que aclarar que para usar esto necesitas **C++ 11**.

Comment: me tira error.. dice `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&' from an rvalue of type 'std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}'|`

Comment: Editado. Hay que pasar el vector como **const**.

Comment: supongo que no tengo opcion, gracias Dementor